# Call a function inside a loop is not working in Python

Tags: python, api, methods, jira

I have a function/method which will create a JIRA ticket. I want to call that function inside a loop so that i can pass different descriptions into the JIRA ticket. I have a CSV file with different service failures so the idea is to create JIRA for each row from the csv file.

My JIRA Method

```
def jira_rest_call(description):
    # Build the text for the JIRA ticket.
    jira_summary = "Pro active Monitoring"
    jira_assignee='USERID'
    jira_description = description
    priority = 'High'
    labels_list = 'Production Failure';
    
    # Build the JSON to post to JIRA
    json_data = '''
    {
        "fields":{
            "project":{
                "id": "25102",
                "key": "ABC"
                
            },
            "assignee":{"name":"%s"},
            "summary": "%s",
            "issuetype":{
                "name":"Story"
            },
            "description": "%s",
            "priority":{"name":"%s"},
            "labels":["%s"]
        } 
    }''' % (jira_assignee,jira_summary, jira_description,priority,labels_list)
   
   # Set the root JIRA URL, and encode the username and password 
    url = 'https://jira-abb.net/rest/api/2/issue'
  
    userpass = 'Z683050' + ':' + '*******'
    encoded_u = base64.b64encode(userpass.encode()).decode()
    headers = {"Authorization" : "Basic %s" % encoded_u}
    headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    # Build the request
    r = requests.post(url,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('Z683050', ''*******'), headers=headers, data=json_data) 
    # Send the request and grab JSON response
    # response = urlopen(restreq, data)

      # Load into a JSON object and return that to the calling function
    return r
```

I am calling this method from a different Python module like this -

```
def jira_creation():
    with open ('test_duplicates_1.csv','r') as csv_file:
        for i in csv_file:
            print([i])
            jira_rest_call([i])
```

My CSV Data looks like this

```
PDFDownloader,Backend failed,100
ImageProcess,NullPointer,200
```

So `jira_creation()` method has invoked `jira_rest_call()` and created a ticket only with the first line but i am expecting two tickets.

What is wrong in this code?

```
with open ('test_duplicates_1.csv','r') as csv_file:
            for i in csv_file:
                print([i])
                jira_rest_call([i])
```

I even tested the print statement(*print([i])*), its printing two times but the method call(*jira_rest_call([i])*) has happened only once.

Comment: Please share the error you get. Also, have you check https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples? Seems it is missing .reader method in your looping

Comment: Perhaps check/read the response object returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not reading the csv file the right way. Try this instead:

```
with open ('test_duplicates_1.csv','r') as csv_file:
  reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
      print(row)
      jira_rest_call(row['<column_name>'])  # I don't know what the column names are in your csv file. Replace with the right one.
```